# managing multiple smart contracts

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, smart-contract-wallets, erc-1155, erc-777

Looking for general feedback or advice about multiple smart contracts, each with unique options, offered by a platform for users.

Is this common?

For example, contract 1 is a barebones contract, costs less GAS to process, whereas contract 5 has all the bells and whistles (costs > 2x GAS to process than the first) ...

What I can tell is that now the user can hold assets across multiple contracts, can be unwieldy. If they want to transfer, they're at higher risk of losing their asset since they could accidentally send to the wrong contract address. Any way to mitigate this?

Any thoughts in general?

Comment: Is this about a set of contracts that you built, or about a set of contracts (wallets?) that the user *might* own?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg it's a set of contracts owned/managed by (built for) the platform

Comment: Because this is very hypotetical question without any concrete examples or source code, there is no way to give any answer that would not be a random guess.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa imagine royalty contracts EIP2981, there are platforms who offered tokens before this, they would have needed to deploy another contract to support this no? now they may have two or more contracts, the additions may cause higher GAS, so is it feasible to offer both royalty ((slightly) higher price) and non-royalty ((slightly) lower price) or should the platform only offer one to avoid confusion? what of assets minted before this change? this is only an example, but there are other use cases

Comment: May cause higher gas is speculation without seeing the contract source code. Actual concrete example is needed to understand how much higher or how much lower some gas consumption is.